# dapr getall: how to do it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dapr

First of all, apologies, I know that this question was posted already but there is only one solution that is pointing to a dead link, no other options. So the response is no longer there.

I am using dapr, docker involved, and I am using it to store some data.

I had this line of code that works:

```
var record = await client.GetStateAsync<Record>(StoreName, id);
```

record is an object, `record.Id = id`

Now I need to do a Getall, so, getting all of the records of type Record.

So this is my code:

```
    var stringList = new List<string>();
    stringList.Add(id);
    var mylist = stringList.AsReadOnly();
    var recordList = await client.GetBulkStateAsync(StoreName, mylist, null);
```

It builds but when running it gets an error as `myList` can't be `null`.

So how do I do this?

Option 1:

having consecutive ids then iterate among them,  that's not a very good solution, and I have to assume a limit value for the ids.

option 2: dropping dapr, not a good solution as it doesn't solve the problem, it would be a workaround as well.

so, how do I do a getAll?

Answer (score 0):

In here https://github.com/dapr/dapr/issues/944, the dapr people suggests creating an object with all of the keys, then retrieving this object first, getting the keys and iterating through them. I guess that there is no getAll implementation at the moment, and by the looks of it, it is not coming any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Define a empty filter and query your data store, it will return all objects.

```
var query = "{\"filter\": {}}";

            var queryResponse = await client.QueryStateAsync<Object>(DAPR_STORE_NAME, query);
```